# Gradle does not find jar in local repository

Tags: android, gradle

Using Android Studio 0.4.6

I've got the following gradle.build file:

apply plugin: 'android'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.my.products.aproduct:aproduct.sdk.java:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The jar is not found when building the project:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.my.products.aproduct:aproduct.sdk.java:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         sva.frontend.android.jpurse:app:unspecified
```

Although I can find the jar and pom file in my local repository (~/.m2) folder. I've checked the maven settings of android studio and they've added a local repository pointing to ~/.m2/repositories

I've also tried adding mavenLocal() and even a hardcoded path to the repository in my gradle file.

I have no clues anymore on what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You are putting `mavenLocal()` in the wrong place.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()        
    }
     dependencies {
        //use your version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'        
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Also I suggest you updating your AS version to the last release (0.5.7)